# What does Islam say about people who have died and buried a while after death?

Tags: fiqh, death, ghusl

My father has passed away a few weeks ago, however when we found him he had already died for 3-4 days. In fact when we go back and see when the last time we spoke to him it was probably a week prior. His body had decomposed to the point where we were not able to perform ghusl before burial.

- What is the ruling on delayed burial in this case? Did he suffer because he was not buried for a week?
- Does this take away from his bad deeds?

Any insight would be helpful, jzk.

Comment: Somewhat relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30812/if-we-found-a-dead-body-somewhere-and-need-to-bury-it-do-we-consider-it-a-musli

Answer (score 1):

It is **not recommended** by most scholars to spend life as a solo. Decomposition of a non prophet dead body is an absolute thing in Allah's infinite wisdom. **Pain suffered by a Muslim upto death** has his sins forgiven is well documented. I fail to find any evidence which says Decomposition causes sins to be forgiven. You have to move on accepting Allah's decree and pray for forgiveness of your Muslim father.